# Mailchimp Post Lists returns HTML document?

Tags: mailchimp-api-v3.0

I am starting my first mailchimp integration

I'm not posting any code as it is in a vertical market language called Dataflex so I don't think it would help explain my question...

I have successfully made GET requests to return the information about all lists

However when I try to POST to the lists endpoint to create a new list ...

The call seems to be received OK

The new list is NOT created

The mailchimp response is not in JSON format but what looks like a complete HTML page starting ...

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<!--[if lt IE 7]><html class="no-js lt-ie9 lt-ie8 lt-ie7"> <![endif]-->
<!--[if IE 7]><html class="no-js lt-ie9 lt-ie8"><![endif]-->
<!--[if IE 8]><html class="no-js lt-ie9"><![endif]-->
<!--[if gt IE 8]><!--><html class="no-js" lang="en"><!--<![endif]-->
    <head>
    <meta name="generator" content="Hugo 0.50" />
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <title>Developer | Mailchimp</title>
```

Has anyone experienced this kind of strange response when it should be returning JSON ?

Thanks in advance

Comment: OK if I just goto us20.api.mailchimp.com in the browser then it looks like I get that page back

Comment: Solved. I'd lost the endpoint somewhere along the way